# Вычисление формулы

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы, числовые-последовательности

Будьте добры, напишите на C++ циклический алгоритм к нижеприведённой задаче. То бишь, поделитесь, пожалуйста, точкой зрения, как выглядит цикл, который перебирает компоненты таким образом, чтобы удовлетворить данное условие.

[image: Условие задачи]
Даны вещественные числа a1, a2, ..., a30 и b1, b2, ..., b30. Вычислить: a1 * a30 + a2 * a29 +...+ a30 * a1
Дано дійсні числа а1, a2, ..., a30 та b1, b2, ..., b30. Обчислити:
a1a30 + a2a29 +...+ a30a1
Дано дійсні числа а1, a2, ..., a30 та b1, b2, ..., b30. Обчислити: a1*a30 + a2*a29 +...+ a30*a1

Моя идея использования вложенных циклов результировалась в неуместную последовательность:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ int i,j,res=0, n;
cin >> n; cout << endl;
srand(time(0));
int* a = new int [n];

for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{ a[i]=rand()%21-10;
cout << a[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl;
 
for (j=n-1; j>=0;j--)
{ 
cout << a[j] << " ";
}
cout << endl;



// В итоге последовательность: a1*a1, a1*a2, a1*a3, a1*a5, a2*a1 ...

for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  for (j=n-1; j>=0;j--)
  { 

    res = a[i]*a[j]; 
    cout << res << " "; }}

delete []a;
    return 0;
}
```

Определённые предположения с задействованием цикла while, затем нижеприведённого "скелета" циклического алгоритма...

```
for (var=0; var<n; var++)
{ for (i=0; i<n; i++) {}
  for (j=n-1; j>=0;j--) {}
}
```

...оказались так же неудовлетворительны.

Мне удалось отдельно вывести на консоль последовательность a1, a2, ..., a30 и последовательность a30, a29, ...,a1:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ int i, n;
cin >> n;
int* a = new int [n];

 for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{ a[i]=rand()%21-10;
cout << a[i] << " ";
 }
 cout << endl;
{ for (i=n-1; i>=0;i--)
cout << a[i] << " "; }

delete []a;
    return 0;
}
```

Решение к задаче должно являться единственным числом. Какой шаг стоит предпринять дальше?

Comment: Вам не нужны вложенные циклы. Разберитесь с индексами и хватит только одного `for` тогда каждый элемент будет вычислять по следующему принципу `a[i]*a[arraycount-i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непонятно, при чем тут последовательность `b`, упомянутая в задаче.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  res = res + a[i] * a[n - 1 - i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Раз уж у нас С++...

```
int* a = new int [n];
...
cout << inner_product(a,a+n,reverse_iterator(a+n),0);
```